# <h1> and <h2> are not displayed as expected in Opera browser

Tags: css, cross-browser, opera

I am using the css above to style my h1 and it works good on most browsers except opera that changes the positioning a lot:

```
h1{
    position:fixed;
    left:5px;
    top:5px;
    color:#111;     
    font-family:'Josefin Sans', Arial, serif;
    font-size:3.3em;
    margin:0px;  
    margin-top: 2px;
    margin-bottom: 2px;
    padding: 0px;;

}
```

I tried replacing h1's with h2's and everything works nice on all browsers again even positioning in opera seems to be good, but now the font-size is not good and the font used is probably browsers default...Is there something I should know about heading in opera that I don't?please advice...!
all other browsers:
[image]

opera:
[image]

EDIT:
the main problem seems to be that it doesn't implement a font I have used from google(that all other browsers do...) but it implements another really similar on  above...

Comment: At this point, I would either bite my tongue and just leave Opera in the cold or load a different style for Opera with JS.

Comment: I don't know why but somehow I think this is a good comment...

Comment: Can you post an example page with what you are seeing and what you are expecting?

Comment: @Brad are there any websites I can upload images for purposes like that?

Comment: Im-im-im-image replacement for Opera? :D

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Have you tried using pixels for the font-size instead of em? Maybe Opera interprets em differently than other browsers...

EDIT - Using em for the font size was not the issue. Neither was the position:fixed attribute. Here was the solution:

problem solved after I removed 'Josefin Sans', and then had them back again...now opera presents with backup fonts, I think the problem was a stupid combination of Cache and of Opera being incapable to load a google font for h1

Comment: Opera is very solid for things like this.  I highly doubt this is the solution.

Comment: You're welcome. What about removing position:fixed to see if that could be the cause? If that doesn't work, the only other thing I can think of is maybe try using another font to see if Opera isn't handling the Josefin Sans font correctly.

Comment: problem solved after I removed 'Josefin Sans', and then had them back again...now opera presents with backup fonts, I think the problem was a stupid combination of Cache and of Opera being incapable to load a google font for h1...

Comment: I didn't know if I should mark your answer as the correct one but it had some good points in the comments so I tried to edit it and give it to you...!

Comment: Thanks! :) Do you want me to edit my original post and put everything in there?

Answer (score 0):

Specifying a font size in ems is meaningless. An em is the width of 'm' *in the current font size.* Font sizes should be specified in points.

Comment: You should use ems for margins and other kinds of spacing when you want them to auto-scale with the font size, which is most of the time. You need to understand that specifying font size in ems is circular and therefore completely meaningless.

Answer (score 0):

"Specifying a font size in ems is meaningless. An em is the width of 'm' in the current font size. Font sizes should be specified in points."

--This is not correct.  em is entirely appropriate for defining font sizes.  em does refer to the current font size, *except* when used to define a font size - then it refers to the *parent* font size.  It would be useless otherwise.

From the w3c spec (http://www.w3.org/TR/CSS21/syndata.html) :

"The 'em' unit is equal to the computed value of the 'font-size' property of the element on which it is used. The exception is when 'em' occurs in the value of the 'font-size' property itself, in which case it refers to the font size of the parent element."